# AngularJs push function validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

When I click 'add item', it adds a new object anyway which should not happen `if (newItem !== 'undefined' || newItem !== '')` .My code just ignores the `if` and I don't know why. Also the `missingNewItemError` doesn't display anything.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('gListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.groceries = [{
        item: 'Tomatoes',
        purchased: false
      },
      {
        item: 'Potatoes',
        purchased: false
      },
      {
        item: 'Bread',
        purchased: false
      },
      {
        item: 'Hummus',
        purchased: false
      },
    ];
    $scope.addItem = function(newItem) {
      if (newItem !== 'undefined' || newItem !== '') {
        $scope.groceries.push({
          item: newItem,
          purchased: false
        });
        $scope.missingNewItemError = '';
      } else {
        $scope.missingNewItemError = 'Please enter an item'
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="gListCtrl">
    <h3>Grocery List</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Purchased</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="grocery in groceries">
        <td>{{grocery.item}}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="grocery.purchased" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <label>New Item :
        <input type="text" ng-model="newItem"/>

        </label>
    <button ng-click="addItem(newItem)">add item</button>
    <h4>{{missingNewItemError}}</h4>

  </div>
  <script src="app.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the string literal of `undefined` and comparing with triple equal sign comparator.

```
if (newItem !== 'undefined' || newItem !== '')
```

When you use the `!==` operator that's called a strict comparator and it means something different to `!=`. This will only trigger if the string is empty or the `newItem` variable is the string `'undefined'` instead of `undefined` or the `newItem` is just an empty string.

Change that to:

```
if (newItem !== undefined || newItem !== '')
```

Or if you want to save more code since an empty string evaluates to `falsey` and a non-empty string to `truthy`

```
if (newItem)
```

A reference for equality comparisons in JavaScript can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still won't work. You were right about the 'undefined' mistake . I found the solution : (!(newItem === undefined || newItem === '')). Now the code works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Angular create a some default functions to validations as `defined` or `undefined` and etc...

as this sample you can use `angular.isUndefined` to check the validation of your property

```
if (angular.isUndefined(newItem) || newItem !== '')
```

or you can create new custom validation and assign it to angular as

```
angular.isUndefinedOrNull = function (val) {
    return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === "" || val === null;
}
```

you can use it to check `null` and `undefined`

```
if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull(newItem))
```